# Neo4j - Import very large CSV into existing Database

Tags: python, csv, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-shell

I'm quite new to Neo4j and already lost with all the out of date documentation and very unclear commands, their effect or speed.

**I am looking for a way to import some very large data fast**.
The data is in B scale for one kind of data, split into multiple CSV, but I don't mind fusing it into one.

Doing a very simple import (load csv ... create (n:XXX {id: row.id})
Is taking ages, especially with a unique index, it takes days.
I stopped the operations, dropped the unique index and restarted, about 2x faster, but still too slow.

I know about neo4j-import (*although deprecated, and there is no documentation on neo4j website about "neo4j-admin import"*). It's already extremely unclear how to do simple things like a conditional something.
The biggest bummer is that **it doesn't seem to work with an existing database**.

**The main question is, is there anyway to accelerate import of very large CSV files with neo4j?**
First with simple statement like create, but hopefully with match as well.
Right now, running a cypher command such as "*match (n:X {id: "Y"}) return n limit 1*" takes multiple minutes on the 1B nodes.

(I'm running this on a server, with 200GB+ of RAM and 48CPUs, so probably not a limitation from hardware point of view).

Comment: Disk IO is also really important ! 
What do you call a very large CSV ? 
What is your Neo4j configuration ? 
Have you done periodic commits ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I shared a bit more details in a gist to not crowd my question: https://gist.github.com/Einharch/23a31f869787950a898fed051e1a6ee0 ... For disk, while not SSDs it's multiple RAIDs of fast disks (the files are read/created very quickly by other soft). Files should fir in RAM also. The server has only Neo4j 3.2.2 community on Ubunto, unmodified.
Yes I am using periodic commits every 100K.

Comment: I changed the from "merge" to "create" now, in the explain command, it seemed like the most performant solution ... The script has been running for 4 days, still not finished. And because it still locks the index (why???) I can't even divide it to run on multiple process ... It's really bothering and I wonder if neo4j is really ready for production?

Comment: @Einharch Did you fix this problem? and seems the gist cannot visit now.